# Understand mvn unit test error with JSON MockHttpServletResponse Test

Tags: java, json, maven, unit-testing

Hi I'm totally new to Maven my Java knowledge is low, my programming is good in other areas but I'm little overwhelmed currently with size of this multimode Maven build I'm trying to get working.

I'm trying to install a Maven build SDK and receive this error when running MVN test:

```
Tests run: 4, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.194 sec <<< FAILURE!
testWriteWithMap(eu.sdk.util.JsonWriterTest)  Time elapsed: 0.181 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: null expected:<{"[b":12,"c":123,"a":"test1"]}> but was:<{"[a":"test1","b":12,"c":123]}>
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:81)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:87)
    at junit.framework.Assert$assertEquals$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
    at eu.digient.sdk.util.JsonWriterTest.testWriteWithMap(JsonWriterTest.groovy:28)

testConvert2JsonStrWithMap(eu.sdk.util.JsonWriterTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: null expected:<{"[b":12,"c":123,"a":"test1"]}> but was:<{"[a":"test1","b":12,"c":123]}>
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:81)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:87)
    at junit.framework.Assert$assertEquals$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
    at eu.digient.sdk.util.JsonWriterTest.testConvert2JsonStrWithMap(JsonWriterTest.groovy:85)
```

I have traced the error to the test file and found the test function here:

```
@Test
    public void testWriteWithMap() {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        Map<String, Object> jsonBean = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        jsonBean.put("a", "test1");
        jsonBean.put("b", 12);
        jsonBean.put("c", new BigDecimal(123));

        try {
            JsonWriter.write(response, jsonBean);

            assertEquals("{\"b\":12,\"c\":123,\"a\":\"test1\"}", response.getContentAsString());
        } catch (HttpMessageNotWritableException e) {
            fail("fail");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            fail("fail");
        }
    }
```

Why is this failing, my assumption is this should be the correct test having inherited this code from a once working on the server project for my new client. I don't really understand what this tests aim is at the moment? Can any one enlighten me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: null expected:<{"[b":12,"c":123,"a":"test1"]}> but was:<{"[a":"test1","b":12,"c":123]}>
```

This states that the equality between expected  and actual fails. Reason behind failure is `assertEquals` - which looks for exact match.

Use : [JSON](https://jsonp.java.net/) or [Gson](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) API for the comparison.

*this should be the correct test having inherited this code from a once working on the server project for my new client.*

Are you sure that it is executed in the parent version of the code ? As per the `Sorted input` parameter, default is set to false and the values are not sorted and also depends on `Sort Keys`. Input order is maintained.

Not a best practice to hard code the output params all the time. Can use the methods defined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)

**EDIT:**

- If the order of the Java object has to be maintained `@JsonPropertyOrder` can be used.
- If you are using `GSON` api,  you can use Serializers to define the input/output order. [Source](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization).
- If you are using `CloverETL` gives you options for maintaining the sorted input order. [Source](http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/index.jsp?topic=/com.cloveretl.gui.docs/docs/jsonwriter.html)

However, there has been a strong recommendation that not to depend on the order of the keys, unlike there is a very very strong reason to do so. Using `containsKey()` of [JsonObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) is highly preferable than to sort and manipulate the order.

Comment: Sorry I'm stupid here but where is this? "As per the Sorted input parameter" I assume I can define unsorted vs sorted. Is this for the assertEquals check?

Comment: It's why I was confused actually - why did the junit test have the order different on the comparison?  Had it always been wrong etc...